# Graphs: Prove that $\operatorname{diam}(G \cdot H) \leq \operatorname{diam}(G)+\operatorname{diam}(H)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be graphs. Prove that $\operatorname{diam}(G \cdot H) \leq \operatorname{diam}(G)+\operatorname{diam}(H)$.

So I understand cross product of graphs but I am not sure where to start on this proof

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Let $(u,v)$ and $(a,b)$ be any pair of vertices in $G \times H$.

Intuitively, to move from $(u,v)$ to $(a,b)$ you can go from $u \to a$ first and then from $v \to b$. That is

$$(u,v) \to (a,v) \to (a,b)$$

So to make it a proof:

What can you say about

$$d[(u,v), (a,v) ]\, \mbox{ and} \, d[(a,v), (a,b) ]$$

Comment: I am not sure if I understand $d[(u,v),(a,v)$ and $d[(a,v),(a,b)]$. Could you expand on this?

Comment: @user1790193 That is the distance, i.e. the length of the shortest path between those vertices...

Comment: So what could I say about the shortest path between those vertices?

Comment: @user1790193 Well, you can find a path in $G \times \{ v \}$...